# Exposing Objective-c object to JavaScript environment in JSON format

Tags: javascript, objective-c

I want to represent any objective-c object in JSON format at RUNTIME, so that a javascript script can use it to access any field/variables/properties through 'dot' notation.

For example,

**Objective-c class for the object could be:**

```
@interface myNativeObject 
   PrimtivieType *pVar;
   CustomClassType *cVar;
@end
```

**Where CustomClassType may contain another object as shown below:**

```
@interface CustomDataType
  PrimitiveType *myVar;
@end
```

**I want to Expose myNativeObject to JavaScript in JSON format, as follows:**

```
    var nativeObjInJavaScript = {
                                  pVar:pval,
                                  cVar:{
                                         myVar:myVarValue
                                  }
                                }
```

**So, now following JavaScript expression shoule work correctly:**

```
var LValue = nativeObjInJavaScript.cVar.myVar;
```

I am thinking of

1.) writing a recursive function which will use Objective-C runtime library to get information about the object and generate the JSON equivalent. Am I on the right track?

2.) Key-Value encoding feature of Objective-c could be of any help in this case?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OS X, WebKit has the mechanism already, read [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001215-BBCBFJCD). You just need to get the window script object and set your Obj-C object there:

```
 WebScriptObject* wso=[webView windowScriptObject];
 [wso setValue:objCobj forKey:@"javascriptName"];
```

You need to specify the method names and properties accessible from the javascript side in

```
 + (BOOL)isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:(SEL)aSelector;
 + (BOOL)isKeyExcludedFromWebScript:(const char *)name;
```

of the class you expose.

On iPhone, the method you can use on `UIWebView` is [stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW21) to construct the javascript object, and the delegate method [`webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006951-CH3-SW6) to receive the info back. If you want to expose generic objects you need to use approach 1), but I don't think that's generically good; `NSObject` can have lots of private ivars which are picked up by the runtime, which you might not want to expose. I guess it's better to give the list of properties you want to expose.

The project [PhoneGap](http://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/tree/master/PhoneGapLib/) heavily uses this technique, so reading its source code might help you.

Comment: Yuji - I want to achieve this on iPhone hence "WebScriptObject" will not be useful for sure. Anyways, thanks for your response. I will look into the PhoneGap source code and will try to write recursive function which can selectively expose desired properties/vars. Thanks.

Comment: When you use `WebScriptObject` then you shouldn't use the webView delegate to receive info back. Instead you should implement `WebScripting` in a custom object and use it to enable JS to call methods in the ObjC program.